# Kubernetes on Simatic IoT2040

Tags: linux, kubernetes, yocto

How to install Kubernetes on Siemens Simatic IoT2040 that is running on example image version 2.2.0 from Siemens?

Comment: [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new image like that.

clone in meta-virtualisation into your poky directory.

```
cd poky-version

git clone -b version https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-virtualization/
```

In the local.conf file add

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "kubernetes"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am getting error while I am trying to build image for Simatic IoT2040
ERROR
 /home/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-extended/upm/upm_git.bb:do_compile
  /home/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake/cmake_3.8.2.bb:do_compile

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
 Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my host machine and I had already installed all the required packages for host machine. Please suggest where I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you use the same version of poky and meta layers?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I had created the image for Simatic iot2040 successfully. Could you tell me how to start Kubernetes on Simatic IoT2040? Is there any command to start the Kubernetes?